# Issue splitting free form text field into two separate columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a column containing both the first and last name of a client that needs to be split into two separate columns. However, being that this is a free form text field I have no control over what someone types in it. I'm was previously splitting by doing the following:

```
SELECT 
LEFT(client_name, CHARINDEX(' ', client_name) -1 ) AS FirstName
RIGHT(x_amr_kpi_past_clients.past_client_name, CHARINDEX(' ', 
REVERSE(x_amr_kpi_past_clients.past_client_name)) -1) AS LastName
FROM Clients
```

Problem is someone entered just "s" without a space. Is there a way I can sanitize the data so if this happens again it will just return NULL?

Comment: Sample data and expected results would help here

Comment: You may also want to take a peek at parsename() or string_split()

Comment: The best way would be to split this in the UI and make both required. Doing this in the back end like you are doing is prone to all sorts of issues. And I should suggest you read this article about storing names in databases. https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, here is two ways to do so

> It's a guess since there is no sample data & expected results

1- Using `CASE` expression

```
SELECT S,
       CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', S) > 0
            THEN LEFT(S, CHARINDEX(' ', S) - 1)
            ELSE S
       END FirstName,
       CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', S) > 0
            THEN SUBSTRING(S, CHARINDEX(' ', S)+1, LEN(S)- (CHARINDEX(' ', S)-1))
            ELSE NULL
       END LastName
FROM
(
  VALUES
  ('First Name'),
  ('Name'),
  ('S')
) T(S);
```

2- Using `PARSENAME()`

```
SELECT S,
       PARSENAME(REPLACE(S, ' ', '.'), 1) FirstName,
       PARSENAME(REPLACE(S, ' ', '.'), 2) LastName
FROM
(
  VALUES
  ('First Name'),
  ('Name'),
  ('S')
) T(S);
```

Comment: This is super helpful! I was previously unaware of the PARSENAME() function. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am not going to comment on your code for this or how often it works.  You can get rid of the error by adding an extra space in the `charindex()` call:

```
CHARINDEX(' ', client_name + ' ')
```